# Timeline with swiperJS Conflicts

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, swiper.js

I have a Timeline on my Website using SwiperJS and several functions to archieve the desired behavior. My problem is, that these functions conflicting each other.

I use the Timeline to navigate the swiper-slides.
when I click a timespan in the timeline the corresponding swiper-slide is supposed to show based on the slideIndex data attribute set for each timespan.

the timeline should have these functionality:

1. slideTo the corresponding slide when clicking on a timespan,
   then set the clicked timespan to active and scroll it to the middle of the viewport.

```
init: function () {
  const timeline = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
  timeline.forEach(function (timespan) {
    timespan.addEventListener("click", function () {
      // Remove active class from all timespans
      timeline.forEach(function (item) {
        item.classList.remove("active");
      });

      // Add active class to the clicked timespan
      timespan.classList.add("active");

      // Scroll to the clicked timespan
      scrollToTimespan(timespan);

      // Slide to the corresponding slide
      let slideIndex = parseInt(timespan.dataset.slideIndex);
      timelineSwiper.slideTo(slideIndex);
    });
  });
},
```

2. Set the timespan which is in the middle of the viewport to active.
   So when a user scrolls the timeline (the timespan have scroll-snap) the centered timespan is
   the active one and it shows it's corresponding slide.

```
const timespans = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".about .container");
let scrolling = false;

// Function to check if an element is in the middle of the viewport
function isElementInViewport(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const viewportHeight =
    window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const middleViewport = viewportHeight / 2;

  return rect.top <= middleViewport && rect.bottom >= middleViewport;
}

// Function to remove the active class from all timespan elements
function removeActiveClass() {
  timespans.forEach((timespan) => {
    timespan.classList.remove("active");
  });
}

// Function to set the active class to the timespan element in the middle of the viewport
function setActiveClass() {
  removeActiveClass();

  timespans.forEach((timespan) => {
    if (isElementInViewport(timespan)) {
      timespan.classList.add("active");
      const slideIndex = parseInt(timespan.dataset.slideIndex);
      timelineSwiper.slideTo(slideIndex);
    }
  });
}

// Function to scroll the timespan into view
function scrollToTimespan(timespan) {
  timespan.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "center",
  });
}

// Call the setActiveClass function initially on window load and on scroll
window.addEventListener("load", setActiveClass);
scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      setActiveClass();
      scrolling = false;
    });
  }
});
```

3. Set the corresponding timespan to active and scroll it to the middle of the viewport, when
   dragging the swiper to the next or previous slide.

```
slideChange: function () {
      if (!this.isBeginning && !this.isEnd) {
        const timeline = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
        const activeSlideIndex = timelineSwiper.activeIndex;

        // Remove active class from all timespans
        timeline.forEach(function (item) {
          item.classList.remove("active");
        });

        // Add active class to the corresponding timespan of the active slide
        timeline[activeSlideIndex].classList.add("active");

        // Scroll to the corresponding timespan
        const activeTimespan = timeline[activeSlideIndex];
        scrollToTimespan(activeTimespan);
      }
    },
```

As mentioned above these functions conflicting each other.
The setActiveClass function restricts me from changing slides based on a click or a drag.
Any idears how I could achieve the functionality mentioned above?

Here is The code snippet:

```js
/* --------------- Timeline Swiper --------------- */

const timelineSwiper = new Swiper(".timeline-swiper", {
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  on: {
    init: function () {
      const timeline = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
      timeline.forEach(function (timespan) {
        timespan.addEventListener("click", function () {
          // Remove active class from all timespans
          timeline.forEach(function (item) {
            item.classList.remove("active");
          });

          // Add active class to the clicked timespan
          timespan.classList.add("active");

          // Scroll to the clicked timespan
          scrollToTimespan(timespan);

          // Slide to the corresponding slide
          let slideIndex = parseInt(timespan.dataset.slideIndex);
          timelineSwiper.slideTo(slideIndex);
        });
      });
    },
    slideChange: function () {
        const timeline = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
        const activeSlideIndex = timelineSwiper.activeIndex;

        // Remove active class from all timespans
        timeline.forEach(function (item) {
          item.classList.remove("active");
        });

        // Add active class to the corresponding timespan of the active slide
        timeline[activeSlideIndex].classList.add("active");

        // Scroll to the corresponding timespan
        const activeTimespan = timeline[activeSlideIndex];
        scrollToTimespan(activeTimespan);
    },
  },
});

/* --------------- Timeline Scroll --------------- */

const timespans = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".about .container");
let scrolling = false;

// Function to check if an element is in the middle of the viewport
function isElementInViewport(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const viewportHeight =
    window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const middleViewport = viewportHeight / 2;

  return rect.top <= middleViewport && rect.bottom >= middleViewport;
}

// Function to remove the active class from all timespan elements
function removeActiveClass() {
  timespans.forEach((timespan) => {
    timespan.classList.remove("active");
  });
}

// Function to set the active class to the timespan element in the middle of the viewport
function setActiveClass() {
  removeActiveClass();

  timespans.forEach((timespan) => {
    if (isElementInViewport(timespan)) {
      timespan.classList.add("active");
      const slideIndex = parseInt(timespan.dataset.slideIndex);
      timelineSwiper.slideTo(slideIndex);
    }
  });
}

// Function to scroll to a timespan element
function scrollToTimespan(timespan) {
  timespan.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "center",
  });
}

// Call the setActiveClass function initially on window load and on scroll
window.addEventListener("load", setActiveClass);
scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      setActiveClass();
      scrolling = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about .container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.05fr 1fr;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; /* For snapping timespan */
  scrollbar-width: thin; /* For Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
}

.about-timeline {
  margin: 500px auto;
}

.timespan {
  max-width: 450px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* snap when scrolling */
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  }

.timespan.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}

.about-info {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 4rem
}

.timeline-swiper .swiper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.info-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.about .text {
  margin: 3rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- --------- Swiper Library --------- -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
    
      <section class="about section" id="about">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="about-timeline">
            <!-- First Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan active" data-slide-index="0">
            Timespan1
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Second Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="1">
            Timespan2
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Third Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="2">
            Timespan3
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Fourth Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="3">
            Timespan4
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Fifth Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="4">
            Timespan5
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Sixth Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="5">
            Timespan6
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="about-info">
            <div class="info-container">
              <div class="swiper timeline-swiper">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <!-- First Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Second Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Third Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Fourth Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Fifth Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Sixth Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so debounce the scroll event did the trick.

```js
/* --------------- Timeline Swiper --------------- */

const timelineSwiper = new Swiper(".timeline-swiper", {
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  on: {
    init: function () {
      const timeline = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
      timeline.forEach(function (timespan) {
        timespan.addEventListener("click", function () {
          // Remove active class from all timespans
          timeline.forEach(function (item) {
            item.classList.remove("active");
          });

          // Add active class to the clicked timespan
          timespan.classList.add("active");

          // Scroll to the clicked timespan
          scrollToTimespan(timespan);

          // Slide to the corresponding slide
          let slideIndex = parseInt(timespan.dataset.slideIndex);
          timelineSwiper.slideTo(slideIndex);
        });
      });
    },
    slideChange: function () {
        const timeline = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
        const activeSlideIndex = timelineSwiper.activeIndex;

        // Remove active class from all timespans
        timeline.forEach(function (item) {
          item.classList.remove("active");
        });

        // Add active class to the corresponding timespan of the active slide
        timeline[activeSlideIndex].classList.add("active");

        // Scroll to the corresponding timespan
        const activeTimespan = timeline[activeSlideIndex];
        scrollToTimespan(activeTimespan);
    },
  },
});

/* --------------- Timeline Scroll --------------- */

const timespans = document.querySelectorAll(".timespan");
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".about .container");
let scrolling = false;

// Function to check if an element is in the middle of the viewport
function isElementInViewport(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const viewportHeight =
    window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const middleViewport = viewportHeight / 2;

  return rect.top <= middleViewport && rect.bottom >= middleViewport;
}

// Function to remove the active class from all timespan elements
function removeActiveClass() {
  timespans.forEach((timespan) => {
    timespan.classList.remove("active");
  });
}

// Function to set the active class to the timespan element in the middle of the viewport
function setActiveClass() {
  removeActiveClass();

  timespans.forEach((timespan) => {
    if (isElementInViewport(timespan)) {
      timespan.classList.add("active");
      const slideIndex = parseInt(timespan.dataset.slideIndex);
      timelineSwiper.slideTo(slideIndex);
    }
  });
}

// Function to scroll to a timespan element
function scrollToTimespan(timespan) {
  scrolling = true;
  timespan.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "center",
  });
}

// Call the setActiveClass function initially on window load and on scroll
window.addEventListener("load", setActiveClass);

scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
scrollContainer.addEventListener("scrollend", () => {
  debounce(scrollEndHandler, 100);
});

function scrollEndHandler() {
  scrolling = false;
}

function scrollHandler() {
  if (!scrolling) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      setActiveClass();
    });
  }
}

function debounce(method, delay) {
    clearTimeout(method._tId);
    method._tId= setTimeout(function(){
        method();
    }, delay);
}
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about .container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.05fr 1fr;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; /* For snapping timespan */
  scrollbar-width: thin; /* For Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
}

.about-timeline {
  margin: 500px auto;
}

.timespan {
  max-width: 450px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* snap when scrolling */
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  }

.timespan.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}

.about-info {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 4rem
}

.timeline-swiper .swiper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.info-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.about .text {
  margin: 3rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- --------- Swiper Library --------- -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
    
      <section class="about section" id="about">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="about-timeline">
            <!-- First Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan active" data-slide-index="0">
            Timespan1
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Second Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="1">
            Timespan2
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Third Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="2">
            Timespan3
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Fourth Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="3">
            Timespan4
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Fifth Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="4">
            Timespan5
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <!-- Sixth Timespan -->
            <div class="timespan" data-slide-index="5">
            Timespan6
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="about-info">
            <div class="info-container">
              <div class="swiper timeline-swiper">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <!-- First Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Second Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Third Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Fourth Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Fifth Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Sixth Timespan -->
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <p class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Error rerum eaque, praesentium, fugiat repudiandae dolorem
                      suscipit consequatur neque nisi harum delectus
                      exercitationem odit expedita tempora ipsum facere, rem hic
                      laudantium?
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```